# On the kuratowski definition of ordered pairs.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Kuratowski gave the following definition for ordered pair,
$$(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$$
Coming to it's geometric explanation, I think of it as a point in Cartesian plane.
Now similarly, what if we take only one argument inside my ordered pair?

My argument is that,
$$(a)=a$$
Because intuitively, $(a)$ is a point on 1-dimensional plane i.e number line.
And at the same time can we use kuratowski definition to prove it(if my argument is true)?

Comment: I’m not sure that intuition is a strong reed to lean on here.

Comment: There is no "geometric explanation" for Kuratowski's definition, it is a technical artifice to *avoid* using numbers to label coordinates the usual way. Nor can you use Kuratowski's definition to "prove" how to represent a singleton, it only says something about pairs. Just pick $a$ or $\{a\}$ or $\{a,\{a\}\}$ or $\{\{a\}\}$, it makes no difference as long as $a$ is recoverable from it.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is the set of all real numbers, $\Bbb C$ is the set of all complex numbers. What point on the plane corresponds to the ordered pair $(\Bbb R, \Bbb C)$? As for "what if we take only one argument inside my ordered pair", the word "pair" indicates two arguments. They can be the same: $(a,a)$ is a valid ordered pair. But it is not $a$. It is a pair with distinguishable elements, both of which happen to be $a$. You can define "tuples" more generally, which comes with a 1-tuple, but even then $(a)$ is a distinct object from $a$ itself, just as $\{a\} \ne a$.

Answer (score 1):

Define an "assignment" (i.e. a class function) $F$ by
$$F(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$$
You can think of $F(x,y)$ as a set-theoretical encoding from the inputs $x$ and $y$. The encoding has the desired meaning of an "ordered pair" since there are two projection functions $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ that satisfy the following property: $\pi_1(F(x,y))=x$ and $\pi_2(F(x,y))=y$. You can think of $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ as set-theoretical decoders that allow us to identify what the first coordinate is (by applying $\pi_1$) or to identify what the second coordinate is (by applying $\pi_2$). I forgo defining $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ explicitly here.

Now you want to introduce another "assignment" $G$ defined by
$$G(x)=\boxed{???}$$
I put three question marks here because you didn't actually define it, but the important thing I gathered was that it takes one input. The map $F$ requires two inputs therefore $F\ne G$. Then you want to argue that $G(x)=x$ and you believe Kuratowski's $F$ map is somehow relevant. I hope I made it clear why your question is perceived as nonsensical.

I'll play along and assume you want to propose $G(x)=x$ by definition. You can think of $G(x)$ as the trivial encoding where nothing happens. Then the projection function $\pi_1$ can also do nothing, i.e., $\pi_1(y)=y$. Then indeed $\pi_1(G(x))=x$ since both $ G $ and $\pi_1$ do nothing to the input $x$.